# In Angular, why does grouping of ng-options make selects go nuts in iOS 8?

Tags: javascript, iphone, angularjs

This is kinda hard to describe. I'm experiencing some odd behaviors with select boxes generated with the ng-options directive. **But only if** I include a "group by" expression. And only on mobile (iPhone) At least it seems to work as expected in the desktop version of Chrome.

What happens is that the select box seems to trigger a change immediately after it gets focus, and the item before the current selected item is selected. Any ideas why this is happening?

- Demo (with iphone): http://jsfiddle.net/remisture/s3oLq5az/embedded/result/
- Code: http://jsfiddle.net/remisture/s3oLq5az/

**Template:**

```
<select ng-model="workout" ng-change="getData(workout)" ng-options="workout as workout.name group by workout.type for workout in workouts | orderBy: ['type', 'name']"></select>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.workouts = [
   {id: 1, name: 'Fran', type: 'Girls'},
   {id: 2, name: 'Cindy', type: 'Girls'},
   {id: 440, name: 'Back squat : 1RM', type: 'Barbell lifts'}
   {id: 413, name: 'Deadlift : 1RM', type: 'Barbell lifts'}
];
```

Comment: This looks like an iOS/Safari bug. I've created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/titololuwe/1/edit?html,output) for this using AngularJS 1.3, but it's the same problem (=> Angular upgrade doesn't help).
The funny thing is that I can reproduce this on iPhone 6, iOS 8.1.3 on Safari, while Chrome works fine.
On iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1.2 the bug is not reproducable. Crazy!

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6569965